# How do I display a static page if there is a database error?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that runs off apache2, and every now and then there is a database error, although I have a custom database error page, how can I display a cached page even if the database is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just **3 step process**:

1. **Create** your custom page
2. **Name** it `db-error.php`
3. **Upload** it to the `wp-content` directory

Comment: That's what I did. But how can I show people a cached version?